# Preventing my doubles from rounding up when using yearsTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", years));

Tags: java, swing, formatting

I am trying to program this calculator in Java as accurately as possible. It takes seconds and converts it to years and then breaks down the days, hours, minutes, and seconds. I've formatted my answers so that my textFields only display the whole number. Unfortunately when i use the % to pull the remainder to convert the rest of my variables it rounds my answers up if my tenths is 5 or more. This is for a GUI, here is the code. I'm guessing it is a tolerance issue.

```
private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            double inputSeconds, years, days, hours, minutes, seconds;


            inputSeconds = Double.parseDouble(inputSecondsTF.getText());
            years = inputSeconds / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;
            days = years % 1 * 365;
            hours = days % 1  * 24;
            minutes = hours % 1 * 60;
            seconds = minutes % 1 * 60;

            yearsTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", years));
            daysTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", days));
            hoursTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", hours));
            minutesTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", minutes));
            secondsTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", seconds));


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 yearsTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)years));
 daysTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)days));
 hoursTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)hours));
 minutesTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)minutes));
 secondsTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)(seconds+0.5)));
```

The numbers should round-down if you use this method. The doubles are converted into integers before being setText'ed (for example, 4.98 becomes 4 and 4.32 becomes 4 as well).

I added the "+ 0.5" for the seconds because we want it to be rounded up. So, if we have 58.7 seconds left, this will happen:
58.7 + 0.5 = 59.2 -> converted into 59.

This also works:

```
 yearsTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)years));
 daysTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)days));
 hoursTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)hours));
 minutesTF.setText(String.format("%d", (int)minutes));
 secondsTF.setText(String.format("%.0f", seconds));
```

Comment: That works for numbers that have remainders. However, when I test it against 31,536,000 seconds = 1 year, it will produce
-numbers for days, hours, minutes, and seconds. I was curious. Do you think I can format my doubles to make rounding UNNECESSARY? I have been exploring rounding mode and BigDecimal, but, I don't have the slightest idea how to implement it. I just started Java this semester and I don't think my textbook even covers it. Thank you, your input is definitely sending me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. I think this way is better.

Comment: did you import any classes up top? I am getting a native method error.

Comment: Scratch that! I was accidentally leaving in the decimal point in. Thank you for your help!